# Find the maximum value of the product xyz?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

IF $x , y , z$  are arbitary positive real numbers satisfying the equation

$$  4xy + 6yz + 8xz = 9$$

Find the maximum value of the product $xyz$.

I dont know from where to begin .

3 variables and one equation.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with lagrange multipliers? I'm guessing not because of the tag, but just checking

Comment: Lagrange Multipliers for constrained extremal points.

Comment: @Alex Becker No.I am not aware of lagrange multipliers.If it is something related to my question.Please let me know

Comment: @vikiiii It's a technique used in calculus for exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: @Alex how i can get to my answer?

Comment: This is the same sort of problem as the one in [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117000/find-the-maximum-possible-value-of-the-equation) of yours. The Wikipedia article on [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) shows you how to solve these; it has some worked out examples.

Answer (score 7):

Arithmetic mean is $\ge$ Geometric mean, i.e. $${{4xy + 6yz + 8xz}\over3} \ge {{(4xy\cdot 6yz\cdot 8xz)}}^{1/3}.$$

Comment: how it will give me value of xyz?

Comment: LHS is AM of 18 things, RHS is not GM of 18 things. I think you get $(4xy+6yz+8xz)/3\ge((4xy)(6yz)(8xz))^{1/3}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, you are right, i have edited the answer.

Comment: @vikiii RHS is $192^{1/3}*xyz^{2/3}$ and LHS is 3.

Comment: Of course, you then have to decide whether the bound you get is actually attained.

Comment: Bound attained at $x=3/4$, $y=1$, $z=1/2$.

Comment: @Andre How did you get the bound ?

Comment: When you use AM-GM, we have $\text{AM}=\text{GM}$ iff terms that are averaged are all equal. So put $4xy=6yz=8xz=3$, solve.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to use the AGM inequality without loss we have to "symmetrize" the three variables. Therefore we replace $x$, $y$, $z$ by
$$x':=4x,\quad y':=3y,\quad z':=6z\ .$$
The AGM inequality then says that
$$\root 3\of {x'^2y'^2z'^2}\leq {x'y' + y'z' + z' x'\over 3}=4xy + 6 yz+8 zx=9\ ,$$
i.e., $x'y'z'\leq 27$,
with equality iff $x'=y'=z'=3$. It follows that
$$xyz = {x'y'z'\over 72}\leq{3\over 8}$$
with equality iff $x={3\over4}$, $y=1$, $z={1\over2}$.

Comment: Thanks . But i want to know How did you think of x′:=4x,y′:=3y,z′:=6z .

Comment: @vikiiii: I wrote $x'=\alpha x$, $\ldots$, and determined $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ such that $4xy={1\over3}x'y'$, $\ldots\ $.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by using weighted arithmetic mean and geometric mean inequality,

> $$\frac{m_1x_1 + m_2 x_2 + m_3 x_3 +...+ m_n x_n}{m_1+m_2+m_3....m_n} > [{x_1^{m_1}x_2^{m_2}x_3^{m_3}x_4^{m_4}....x_n^{m_n}}]^{\frac{1}{m_1m_1m_2m_3.....m_n}}$$